# Malicious process detected on Powershell while working on my React Native project, what should I do?

Tags: security, powershell, virus, malware, anti-virus

My Rav Antivirus showed me this message while working on my React Native project. What does it mean and what should I do?? I was working on my college project and i'm not familiar with security and cyberattacks

Here's the warning message

[image: Here's the warning message]

Comment: Do a full scan with Windows Defender, and it there is still an issue, look in the WD Scan Options and do a Offline Scan.

Comment: The obfuscated command is just `Start "http://localhost:19002"` by the way.

Comment: Create an exception for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter, as decoded by @DanielB, is :
`Start "http://localhost:19002`.

According to
[Getting Started with the React Native](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Getting-Started-React-Native)
this is a normal occurrence:

> Run yarn start or npm start. Wait Expo CLI to start. Expo CLI opens
> the management interface on the http://localhost:19002/ address.
>
> The React Native application was generated with Expo. Expo is a set of
> tools built around React Native to help you quickly start an app and,
> while it has many features.

This is most likely just the normal way of interfacing with React,
so Windows Defender is just being overly cautious.

I suggest to create an exception for the application. See
[Add an exclusion to Windows Security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26).